# Permissioned relationships removed when contact registers for an Event

Tags: civievent, permissions

For each of our member organizations, we define relationships between each org and individuals so individuals can inherit the organization's membership.

For each organization, we grant one of the individuals with a permissioned relationship so they can update their organizational contact details.

We recently launched an event registration form in civiEvent. And we've discovered that when an individual signs up for an event, if they had a permissioned relationship with the organization, that permissioned relationship is disabled. We can see in the Change log the permission states being changed from 1 to 0.

Can anyone shed light on why this would occur when they register for an event?

Comment: it could be helpful if you could replicate this issue on eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org, so we can get it lodged as a bug if it exists there too

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I did test on dmaster.demo -- and it doesn't happen, although I note that dmaster.demo is version 5.44 and I'm running 5.42.1.

Comment: Try on http://drupal.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1 if you want to compare to a 'released' version

Comment: Suggesting this because what you are describing sounds incorrect, and am trying to confirm if a/ you have something unusual affecting your site or b/ this is a bug that has been fixed

Comment: Are you using the 'related permissions' extension? If so, does (this)[https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions/issues/35] describe your issue?  And does the PR fix it?  If so, please leave a comment on that PR.

Comment: and the rest of the url .... /issues/35. guessing comments cut them short

Comment: Yes, that is the issue -- I actually connected with Brian, who posted the issue and PR